# Firebase CLI: "Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)"

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I just used the Firebase CLI to init a static hosting project. What exactly happens when you enable the "configure as a single-page app" option? I'm looking for a description of exactly which files are modified, and what kind of effect this has on the Firebase backend.

[image: Screenshot of firebase init command]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that option. Can you show where to enable that/where it's documented?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen check out the screenshot that I added to my question

Answer (score 123, accepted):

That option simply sets a flag in the `firebase.json` file to redirect all URLs to `/index.html`.

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

See the [documentation of Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) for more information, which also contains this fuller example:

> ```
> "hosting": {
>   // ...
>
>  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
>   "rewrites": [ {
>     // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
>     "source": "**",
>     "destination": "/index.html"
>   }, {
>     // Serves index.html for requests to both "/foo" and "/foo/**"
>     // Using "/foo/**" only matches paths like "/foo/xyz", but not "/foo"
>     "source": "/foo{,/**}",
>     "destination": "/index.html"
>   }, {
>     // Excludes specified pathways from rewrites
>     "source": "!/@(js|css)/**",
>     "destination": "/index.html"
>   } ]
> }
> ```

Comment: With this config http://localhost:5000/qqq renders but not http://localhost:5000/qqq/www how can I fix this issue? Second link does not renders index.html

Comment: How can we also write an API/functions here then? So for example: 'somewebsite.com/api' which would also be redirecting to a function but also has a root somewebsite.com using ```**```

Comment: Thanks for flagging. I added the more complete example from the linked documentation to help reduce that risk.

Comment: If you're using React, this will allow your JS to redirect to each route as intended if you are using React Router as your routing system

Answer (score 31):

Full example:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you set it to yes, then all invalid URLs like `www.example.com/some-invalid-url` will be redirected to `index.html` of your site which is a good thing. You can also set it to your custom `404.html`.

**firebase.json**

{

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "pubic",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```

Bonus:  set the `cleanUrls` to `true` to remove `.html` extensions from your deployed website urls else all urls without `.html` will redirect to `index.html`.

Answer (score 6):

As a note: if you would like to have Server-Side Rendering (SSR), type **No** and set up your `rewrites` as follow:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "function": "angularUniversalFunction",
    "source": "**"
  }
]
```

After all, whatever you will choose you can always change this in a **firebase.json** file.

Answer (score 4):

### Official Firebase explanation:

We had used that option last year (Q1 & Q2) but it seemed to do nothing, but nowadays when we apply it, definitely things work very different.
The complete official explanation of what it does comes in here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites

There's even some useful information about Headers usage in the next section of the same page.