# Configuring a single page Create-React-App on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, buildpack

With Firebase Hosting, when you deploy an app [you are asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667626/firebase-cli-configure-as-a-single-page-app-rewrite-all-urls-to-index-html) whether to rewrite all urls to /index.html. This means [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) routes would be properly fired whether they are accessed directly or navigated to from the homepage.

We use [Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and [Create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) to deploy to Heroku. How can we rewrite all the URLs to /index.html in the same manner?

Following [this issue](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/issues/86), explaining about the [routes](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-routing-clean-urls) directive, I configured a static.json in the root to no avail:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/images/*": "/images/",
    "/legal/*": "/images/",
    "/media/*": "/media/",
    "/fav/*": "/fav/",
    "/styles/*": "/styles/",
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use an utility like serve to help you with it. https://vijayt.com/post/deploying-react-app-heroku/

Comment: You can also use this hack with `http-server` https://github.com/http-party/http-server/pull/513/files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `static.json` file in the project root with the following content:

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

More [here](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-routing-clean-urls).