# I have a react website deployed with heroku. Heroku displays a backslash on direct navigation to subpages. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I have a front end website done in react deployed with heroku. When you navigate to the main page it displays fine but when you try to navigate to a subpage like www.example.com/about it just displays a backslash. i can get to the subpages by clicking on my navigation buttons but typing in that exact url just takes me to the page with only a back slash appearing. I was thinking that I need to somehow use history from react-router-dom but don't know how any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched for solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=heroku+url+rewrite What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to search but have come up with nothing similar to the problem I am encountering. I am using react-router-dom for routing and everything is fine locally. When the app is deployed on heroku i can not directly navigate to subpages. I am wondering if it could be a react-router-dom problem and i am missing some type of configuration.

Comment: So creating a json file in the root doesn't work? (described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503348/configuring-a-single-page-create-react-app-on-heroku)

Comment: I am using my own custom webpack configuration. Looks like that package generates one automatically? I guess my best route is to look into that package if my problem can be solved using it.

Comment: Using that library solved my problem thanks