# How to disable firebase's 404 page for an angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-routing, firebase-hosting

I have an angular app which is deployed with firebase to production.

The App includes following redirect

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  // some others
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },
];
```

On local environment this works like required, an undefined path is redirected -> HomeComponent is visible.

On the deployed app, however, the user is redirected to a firebase 404 page

[image]

How can I disable the firebase page, so that the user sees the HomeComponent, when he tries to access a not existing page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to configure Firebase Hosting to serve all URLs to a single HTML file, typically index.html in the root of your deployment.  In that case, you'll want to have this in your firebase.json as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

See also: [Firebase CLI: "Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667626/firebase-cli-configure-as-a-single-page-app-rewrite-all-urls-to-index-html)