# Do i configure my firabase application to be a single-page app if Im using nextJS (that is ssr)?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js13

Ive just started a NextJS app with google firabase and as I ran "firebase init" it asked me : "Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?"
do I choose y/n ?

(nextJS is an ssr not spa)

Ive choose N but I dont know if itll cause any problems in the future development of the app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase CLI: "Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667626/firebase-cli-configure-as-a-single-page-app-rewrite-all-urls-to-index-html)